# Angular, Google Maps, How to get list of markers from map and use onClick event on them?

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-markers, angular5

I'm using angular module AGM for Angular 2+ to using Google-Map-Api.

https://angular-maps.com/

I have directive that drawing on map waypoints as markers from Google Map Directions Service.

Now I want to handle event onClick on every marker on map and add my tooltips depending on marker position.

But I don't know how to get list of markers form map object. There is not any method like "getMarkers()".

I didn't manualy add markers to map, google.maps.DirectionsRenderer added them from GoogleMapsDirections service response, so I don't have list of existing markers at this point.

My directive code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'agm-map-directions'
})
export class DirectionsMapDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  private waypoints: Waypoint[];
  @Input()
  private origin: string;
  @Input()
  private destination: string;
  @Input()
  private optimizeWaypoints: boolean;
  @Input()
  private travelMode: string;

  constructor (private gmapsApi: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.renderDirections();
  }

  renderDirections() {
    this.gmapsApi.getNativeMap().then(map => {
      let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsService.route({
        origin:  this.origin,
        destination: this.destination,
        waypoints: this.waypoints,
        optimizeWaypoints: this.optimizeWaypoints,
        travelMode: this.travelMode
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          //There I want to handle markers onClick event
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

My template:

```
<div id="map">
  <agm-map *ngIf="mapLoaded"
           style="height: 500px"
           [zoomControl]="false"
           [disableDefaultUI]="false"
           [disableDoubleClickZoom]="true"
           [streetViewControl]="false">
    <agm-map-directions
      [waypoints]="waypoints"
      [origin]="supplierInfo.origin"
      [destination]="supplierInfo.destination"
      [optimizeWaypoints]="true"
      [travelMode]="'DRIVING'"></agm-map-directions>
  </agm-map>
</div>
```

Is exist any method to retrieve simply markers list from map object?

Or maybe some other solution to archieve same goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately above solution didn't work in my case, maybe beacuse of my directive, I don't know.

But I found other solution.

In my directive I added:

```
directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
```

Now markers doesn't appears automatically. 
And I adding them manually from response route, there I have all markers positions on Map in LatLng.

Something like that:

```
renderDirections() {
    this.gmapsApi.getNativeMap()
      .then(map => {
        let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsService.route({
          origin:  this.origin,
          destination: this.destination,
          waypoints: this.waypoints,
          optimizeWaypoints: this.optimizeWaypoints,
          travelMode: this.travelMode
        }, (response, status) => {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
            let route = response.routes[0];
            this.mapService.addMarkersToMap(route, map);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

When I adding markers manually, I can set OnClick listeners and add infoWindow with buttons.

```
  addMarker(location, map) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: location.lat(),
        lng: location.lng()
      },
      map: map
    });

    marker.addListener('click',  () => {
      let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'some HTML content'
      });
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <agm-map [latitude]="latitude1" [longitude]="longitude1" [zoom]="zoom" [usePanning]='true'>
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let obj of getGoogleData; let i = index" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(obj)" [latitude]="obj.latitude" [longitude]="obj.longtitude"
        [label]="a">
        <agm-info-window>
            <strong>{{obj.title}}</strong>
        </agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
```

Above snippet help you to get multiple markers on map.
As you can see, we have marker component to displayed multiple records and pass object to marketclick function to render title/data to display end-user